# How to keep sourcecode folder structure on Jsdoc

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc

I have created the source code document with Jsdoc, but all the source code files are currently in parity.

As shown below.

[image: Capture]

How to keep sourcecode folder structure on [Jsdoc](https://jsdoc.app/)

I am implementing the following in all source code files , but all the source code files are currently in parity.

Util.js

```
/**
* @module src~common~Util
* @description 共通メソッド（ストリング処理など）
*/
```

BootstrapModal.js

```
/**
* @module src~components~common~BootstrapModal
* @description BootstrapModalでカスタマイズしたエラー画面
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

JSDocs doesn't understand folder structure. If you want to mirror your folder structure I believe you could implement `namespaces` to achieve a similar structure.

```
/**
 * My namespace.
 * @namespace
 */
var MyNamespace = {
    /** documented as MyNamespace.foo */
    foo: function() {},
    /** documented as MyNamespace.bar */
    bar: 1
};
```

-- via [Jsdoc.app](https://jsdoc.app/tags-namespace.html)